# Coloring Background Pictures

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, layers, images, image-editing

Created the following image (or rather, just changed the text to Digital Electronics). How to change the white color of the background of the picture to a suitable color or picture (image) (specifically with the indication of Photoshop tools or possibly using markup without photoshop)? I'm new, so please don't ban me

[image]

Comment: i'd suggest you also check some basic Photoshop tutorials, Adobe itself has a series of video tutorials for beginners: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/ps-basics-fundamentals.html

Answer (score 1):

The PNG image you posted already has a transparent background.  So all you need to do is to place that image on a layer above another image,  or create a new background layer below and fill it with a colour.

Example

[image]

If you want to use the logo on a web page, since the PNG already has transparency, any background you choose on a web page will show through the transparent areas.

Comment: How does to place that image on a layer above another image?
How does create a new background layer below and fill it with a color? I am a newbie, so please point by point to explain how to perform the above steps

Comment: Open an image to use as a background, and then click File > Place - and choose the PNG logo you made. Or to add a new layer, click Layer > New > Layer. You can click and drag the layers in the layers panel if you want to move them up or down.  Use Edit > Fill to fill a layer with colour.  If you are unfamiliar with the concept of layers in Photohsop, it might be worthwhile having a look for [some beginner tutorials on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=photoshop+beginner+tutorial+layers). There are lots!

Comment: I work in the Russified version of Photoshop and in it in the File menu there are only 2 items with the word Place: 1. Place embedded ..., Place related. Which of these two points should be used to insert my PNG file as a foreground?

Comment: You can use either, it doesn't matter which one you choose. In English these options are Place Embedded, or Place Linked.  If you place a linked file, it will be placed as a Smart Object in Photoshop on a new layer, If you place it embedded, it will embed the image within the photoshop document as a new layer.  If you don't understand these basics you really need to take some beginner tutorials.